# Service worker & client communication. Fetch Event finished

Tags: javascript, service-worker, service-worker-events

I am trying to communicate a Service worker with a client in a bidirectional way. My aim is to delegate the processing of the request to the client and come back to the service worker with a proper response. The sequence of steps are the following:

Service Worker:

1. The Service worker gets a request
2. It checks if it must be ignored or properly managed
3. A message with the request and a correlation ID is created
4. The message is sent to the client via the Incoming message
5. The pair {id: event} is registered in Messages store

Client:

1. A request message comes via the Incoming Channel
2. The message is destructured to get the correlation ID & the request
3. A proper response is created for the request
4. The response & correlation ID is sent back to worker via the Outgoing Channel

Service Worker:

1. A response message comes via the Outgoing Channel
2. The message is destructured to get the correlation ID & the response
3. The pending message for this ID is retrieved from the Messages store
4. A new Response object is created for the response
5. The response object is returned via `respondWith`

This is my Service Worker:

```
const INSTALL   = 'install'
const ACTIVE    = 'activate'
const FETCH     = 'fetch'
const MESSAGE   = 'message'
const INSTALLED = 'Worker Installed'
const ACTIVATED = 'Worker Activated'
const FETCHING  = 'Worker fetching'
const ICHANNEL  = 'whale-ichannel'
const OCHANNEL  = 'whale-ochannel'
const HEADERS   = { 'Content-Type' : 'text/javascript' }
const PREFIX    = '/whale/'

let toJson   = JSON.stringify
let toJs     = JSON.parse
let Messages = new Map ()
let idx      = 0
let iChannel = new BroadcastChannel (ICHANNEL) // Incoming Channel
let oChannel = new BroadcastChannel (OCHANNEL) // Outgoing Channel

self.addEventListener (INSTALL, function (event) {

  console.log (INSTALLED)
  self.skipWaiting ()

})

self.addEventListener (ACTIVE, function (event) {

  console.log (ACTIVATED)
  event.waitUntil (clients.claim ())
  oChannel.addEventListener (MESSAGE, function ({ data }) {

    let id       = data.id
    let response = data.response
    let message  = Messages.get (id)

    Messages.delete (id)
    message.send (response)

  })
})

self.addEventListener (FETCH, async function (event) {

  if (isRequest (event)) await doRequest (event)

})

function isRequest (event) {
  let { request } = event
  let { url     } = request
  let uri  = new URL (url)
  let path = uri.pathname
  let ok   = path.startsWith (PREFIX)
  return ok
}

function getRequest (event) {
  let { request  } = event
  let { url      } = request
  let { referrer } = request
  let   headers    = toJs (toJson (request)) || {}

  return {
    url,
    referrer,
    headers
  }
}

function getResponse (data) {
  let headers  = HEADERS
  let text     = data
  let response = new Response (text, { headers })
  return response
}

function doRequest (event) {
  let request    = getRequest (event)
  let {id, wait} = getMessage (event)
  iChannel.postMessage ({ id, request })
  return wait
}

function getMessage (event) {
  let signal
  let wait = new Promise (function (ok) { signal = ok })
  let id   = idx++
  Messages.set (id, {
    send : function (data) {
      let response = getResponse (data)
      event.respondWith (response) // [1]
      signal (data)
    }
  })
  return { id, wait }
}
```

This is my Client:

```
const ICHANNEL = 'whale-ichannel' // Incoming Channel
const OCHANNEL = 'whale-ochannel' // Outgoing Channel

// Register worker ...

let iChannel = new BroadcastChannel (ICHANNEL)
let oChannel = new BroadcastChannel (OCHANNEL)
iChannel.addEventListener (MESSAGE, async function ({ data }) {
  let { id      } = data
  let { request } = data
  let response    = MyFancyResponse (...)
  oChannel.postMessage ({
    id,
    response
  })
})
```

When I run this code the following message error is emitted. See [1] in the Service Worker code. Please notice the entire communication flow is correctly executed.

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'respondWith' on 'FetchEvent': The event handler is already finished.
```

If I do not misunderstand, that means when the worker is abandoned to find the client-side the fetch event is finished. So my approach is not valid. My question is: how can be done this kind of two-way communication where the request-response process is split via message events?

Comment: you need `promise`s. Don't ask me how to fix it though

Answer (score 2):

I think, the problem is, that the onFetch event needs immediate response with
event.respondWith()

If the onFetch doesn't get an event.respondWith, it generates one, and You cannot pass Your response later, and You'll get this error: The event handler is already finished.

So, instead of

```
self.addEventListener (FETCH, async function (event) {
  if (isRequest (event)) await doRequest (event)
})
```

I'd try

```
self.addEventListener (FETCH, function (event) {
    event.respondWith( ( async function() {
        if (isRequest (event)) return await doRequest (event); // note the RETURN
    }) () ); // note the (), what will call the inline async function to get a promise
})

and change the inner event.respondWith(xxx) to return xxx;
```

Please tell, if this solves the problem.